# Data "member not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, vector, initializer-list

I'm trying to create a vector which will store objects. I have added to the header file of the class as a private data member.

I am trying to initialize this vector as being empty (so that I can add objects to it later on in the program) but when I compile this program to test, this error is returned:

> ...error: '_bookingVector' was not declared in this scope|

I think the problem is with my initialization list on my default constructor(_bookingVector is obviously the vector):

```
Schedule::Schedule() : _bookingVector()
{ }
```

Is my syntax wrong? Or are vectors initialized differently?

Here is my code:

Schedule.h

```
#ifndef SCHEDULE_H
#define SCHEDULE_H
#include "Booking.h"
#include <vector>    
using namespace std;


class Schedule
{    
    public:
        Schedule();
        void AddBooking(int bday, int btime, int btrainer, int bid);
        void RemoveBooking(int bday, int btime);
        void DisplaySchedule();
        void DisplayAvailableTimeSlots();    
        //For Testing
        void DisplayDebug();

    private:
        vector<Booking> _bookingVector;   

};    
#endif // SCHEDULE_H
```

Schedule.cpp

```
#include "Schedule.h"
#include "Booking.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 

Schedule::Schedule() : _bookingVector()
{ }    

void AddBooking(int bday, int btime, int btrainer, int bid){    
    Booking bookingObject(bday, btime, btrainer, bid);
    _bookingVector.push_back(bookingObject);    

}


void DisplayDebug(){

    for(int i = 0; i < _bookingVector.size(); ++i){    
        cout << _bookingVecotr[i] << endl;    
    }    
}
```

I'm very eager to learn what I'm doing wrong and fix it.

Comment: Are you sure the error is not about `Schedule::Schedule()` and not `AddBooking()` a few lines below? It should probably be `Schedule::AddBooking()`.

Comment: Yeah completely  overlooked that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with the constructor, which looks fine if unnecessary<sup>1</sup>. The issue is that you have defined `AddBooking` and `DisplayDebug` as non-member functions, but these should be members in order to access other members of the class.

Modify the definitions to be in the scope of the `Schedule` class thus:

```
void Schedule::AddBooking(int bday, int btime, int btrainer, int bid) { ...
     ^^^^^^^^^^

void Schedule::DisplayDebug(){ ...
     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, don't say `using namespace std` in a header file (I'd go further and say don't say it anywhere but there isn't universal agreement on that.)

---

<sup>1 Your default constructor does not do anything that the compiler-generated one wouldn't do. You can safely remove it.</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much man! I feel like an idiot haha. Coming to C++ from C# so its taking me time to adjust.